# Way to perfectly forward an argument. Need to improve this

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, perfect-forwarding

Tried to make universal solution for my template function GenerateDictionary(...) to accept both rvalue and lvalue as generator.

This works, but I'm not sure that this is a correct way of making perfect forwarding here. I'll be happy to see any suggestions how to improve this example.

```
std::string GenerateWord(std::mt19937& generator, int max_length) {
    const int length =
        std::uniform_int_distribution(1, max_length)(generator);
    std::string word;
    word.reserve(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        word.push_back(
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int>('a', 'z')(generator));
    }
    return word;
}

template <template <typename> typename Container, typename Rand>
Container<std::string> GenerateDictionary(Rand&& generator, int word_count,
                                          int max_length) {
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    words.reserve(word_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; ++i) {
        words.push_back(
            GenerateWord(std::forward<Rand&>(generator), max_length));
    }
    return Container(words.begin(), words.end());
}
```

I understand that perfect forwarding may be pointless here, but anyway I want to know the safe way to use it here. Tried this to avoid the function to accept anything except mt19937.

```
template <typename T>
class CanReserve {
    struct Small {
        char c;
    };
    struct Large {
        char arr[2];
    };

    template <typename C>
    static Small test(decltype(&C::reserve));

    template <typename C>
    static Large test(...);

   public:
    enum { value = sizeof(test<T>()) == sizeof(Small) };
};

template <typename Rand,
          typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<Rand, std::mt19937>>>
std::string GenerateWord(Rand&& generator, int max_length) {
    const int length =
        std::uniform_int_distribution(1, max_length)(generator);
    std::string word;
    word.reserve(length);
    auto letter_distr = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>('a', 'z');
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        word.push_back(letter_distr(generator));
    }
    return word;
}

template <template <typename...> typename Container, typename Rand,
          typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<Rand, std::mt19937>>>
Container<std::string> GenerateDictionary(Rand&& generator, int word_count,
                                          int max_length) {
    Container<std::string> words;
    if constexpr (CanReserve<Container<std::string>>::value) {
        words.reserve(word_count);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < word_count; ++i) {
        words.push_back(
            GenerateWord(std::forward<Rand>(generator), max_length));
    }
    return words;
}
```

Comment: `std::forward<Rand&>(generator)` should be `std::forward<Rand>(generator)`. But since `GenerateWord` takes in a `std::mt19937&`, its pointless to forward.

Comment: The goal I'm trying to reach is to make both of these ways to work without changing the functions: ```std::vector<std::string> keys =  GenerateDictionary<std::vector>(
            std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}, 1500, 10);``` and  ```auto rand = std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()}; std::vector<std::string> keys =
        GenerateDictionary<std::vector>(rand, 1500, 10);```

Comment: Unrelated: Creating a new `uniform_int_distribution<int>` for each `push_back` isn't optimal. `uniform_int_distribution`s keep a state so you should preferably create one before the loop and use the same distribution through the loop.

Comment: @ViktorKustov You're welcome! Other than that, I don't think this is a good place to do perfect forwarding. If you changed the signature of `GenerateWord` to also take a generator by a forwarding reference, it'd be better but what happens when you forward anything?  You risk loosing the resources it holds. I don't think that's an issue for `mt19937` but still. You should simply pass it by reference here.

Comment: @ViktorKustov: "*to accept both rvalue and lvalue as generator.*" You shouldn't want that. Random bit generators *ought* to be preserved and used, not created as one-offs. Allowing rvalues here is a code smell.

Comment: One minor improvement could be to not create an intermediate `std::vector<std::string>` but to populate the output container directly: [example](https://godbolt.org/z/hMEEenaeM)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank You for great example. Corrected my code and posted below. Have to work with c++17, so "requires" will not work. Thanks!

Comment: @ViktorKustov If you can't use C++20, you could create a type trait to check if the `Container` supports `reserve`, but that was maybe a side track. :) If you've updated your code, put it in the actual question instead of as an answer. Answers that doesn't actually answer the question will get downvoted and removed, so I'd remove it quickly to avoid flak :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Updated with a type trait. Works for me. I'm a beginner, so many of my exercises have no practical use. The only goal is to make them work safely and correctly))

Comment: @ViktorKustov Great! If you want to force the user to use `mt19937`, then simply take it by reference. I recommend that you instead make a trait that just tests if ´Rand` meets the requirements. [C++ concept example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_random_bit_generator) - if you even need to. I'd just leave that to a compilation error. Note that you shouldn't forward the generator. You can only safely forward things _once_. The next time you forward it ... who knows what state it is in? Also, when you create and populate `Container<std::string> words;` you don't ...

Comment: ... have to create yet another one that you return. Just `return words;` and NRVO will most probably kick in.  [my modifications](https://godbolt.org/z/PzPed9EdW). Another note: Since you accept any container as a template parameter, be aware that not all of then can `push_back`. You may need traits for `push_back`, `push`, `insert` etc. You can perhaps create a `std::conditional` that selects the proper `std::back_inserter` or `std::inserter` for the container.